# Does too many console errors affect browser performance?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, error-handling, console, out-of-memory

I have a web app that periodically checks via HEAD method existence of remote files. 404 response to fetch generates a console error. When the web app runs for longer time period, I see several thousands errors in the console. I don't see any lack of performance, but shouldn't I worry when the number grows?

The concern is that I can scroll all these errors, so obviously they are in some buffer that grows in time. I hope major browsers have their code protected to avoid depletion of available memory, but I can't find anything about this anywhere. I'd prefer not to call `console.clear()` to spot non-fetch errors.

The app runs on mobile browsers mostly if it matters. The app uses WebSQL, so the browsers that I am concerned about are mostly webkit/blink based (Chrome, Opera). I can accept an answer related solely to mobile Chrome.

Comment: Maybe you can just make an experiment. Try without any console log, and then do the same action but with a loop which spam of log, and see if you have a several difference.

Comment: @Elikill58: I made an experiment with 50k errors, but even if it passed 1M errors+, I can't be sure what other factors (like time) affects the performance (I tested error generating for 3 days). Maybe I could just wait for customer's feedback, but I'd prefer to know if it can be a source of problems.

Comment: I understand. From my experience, It can be an issue if you are doing something on mouse move event. Personnally, I was getting error are this event, and I was losing frame rate (I was on angular).
So, It can be a reason of lag